# Run ignores argument -Dhttp.address=****

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I have the problem that when I start my play framework server on my server in developer mode that I cannot specify the HTTP-Port the server should listen on.
When I try the following command the HTTP-Address is always ignored:

```
./play "run -Dhttp.address=192.168.1.1 -Dhttp.port=8080"
```

The port is correctly set but not the address as it can be seen on this output:

[image]

When I run the server in production mode with `start` the address is correctly set and everything works. But for developing purposes I want to reload and compile all files whenever they have been changed, so I can always work with the up-to-date code.
I've already tried a lot of possibilities but couldn't solve the problem so far. Hope someone can give me some hints of how to solve this. Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to like this answer. For Play 2.2, that's exactly what the [code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/core/server/NettyServer.scala) (on GitHub).

The `start` uses the port and address properties:

```
  val server = new NettyServer(
    new StaticApplication(applicationPath),
    Option(System.getProperty("http.port")).fold(Option(9000))(p => if (p == "disabled") Option.empty[Int] else Option(Integer.parseInt(p))),
    Option(System.getProperty("https.port")).map(Integer.parseInt(_)),
    Option(System.getProperty("http.address")).getOrElse("0.0.0.0")
  )
```

The `run` uses just the port property:

```
  def mainDevHttpMode(sbtLink: SBTLink, sbtDocHandler: SBTDocHandler, httpPort: Int): NettyServer = {
    mainDev(sbtLink, sbtDocHandler, Some(httpPort), Option(System.getProperty("https.port")).map(Integer.parseInt(_)))
  }

  private def mainDev(sbtLink: SBTLink, sbtDocHandler: SBTDocHandler, httpPort: Option[Int], httpsPort: Option[Int]): NettyServer = {
    play.utils.Threads.withContextClassLoader(this.getClass.getClassLoader) {
      try {
        val appProvider = new ReloadableApplication(sbtLink, sbtDocHandler)
        new NettyServer(appProvider, httpPort,
          httpsPort,
          mode = Mode.Dev)
      } catch {
        case e: ExceptionInInitializerError => throw e.getCause
      }

    }
  }
```

You can however a) call `NettyServer` yourself with `ReloadableApplication` and the address you want to use (although I've never tried this); or b) use a non-Play solution where you modify the networking settings to use a different interface for the default address.